# AT Commands to send/publish data to azure iot hub using sim808

Tags: esp32, arduino-uno, azure-iot-hub

I am using esp32 dev module as a microcontroller and  i have connected temperature sensor, accelerometer and sim808 module i want to send the data at every 1 second to the azure iot hub

I tried the at command to connect to GPRS but unable to connect. I am expecting the lists of AT command that will help me in publishing the data to azure iot hub platform.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty broad so let me give you some resources to get you started.

Here are a few libraries that might help:

[TinyGSM](https://github.com/vshymanskyy/TinyGSM) - This will handle communication with your SIM808 using AT commands. They have some great examples. 
[PubSubClient](https://github.com/knolleary/pubsubclient) - is an MQTT library that you can use with TinyGSM to connect to Azure over MQTT. 
[SSLClient](https://github.com/govorox/SSLClient/tree/master) - is a library for the ESP32 that can work with both the above mentioned libraries to provide TLS support.

Here is an example that ties all of these together to connect to Azure over TLS using a SIM800L modem with the ESP32. [mqtt_gsm_SIM800L_Azure_x509_Device_Twin](https://github.com/govorox/SSLClient/blob/master/examples/Esp32/mqtt_gsm_SIM800L_Azure_x509_Device_Twin/mqtt_gsm_SIM800L_Azure_x509_Device_Twin.ino). With a few modifications you should be able to get this working with the SIM808. Good luck.